# Pass arbitrary struct as function parameter

Tags: go

I'm processing binary files.  I need a function which takes an arbitrary structure and returns an array of those structures.  How would I do this?  Below is a simple example of what I'm trying to accomplish.  Currently, I have a function for each of the structures.  The only difference is in the line:

```
dataBuf, err := make([]arbitrary_struct_type, numRecs)
```

```
type structA struct {
   id int32
   sDate float64
   name  string
}

type structB struct {
   area int32
   polygon string
}

type structC struct {
   sTime  float64
   eTime  float64
   tSlice int32
   kml    string
}

func readDataset(grp *Group, arbitrary_struct_type type) ([]arbitrary_struct_type type, error) {
   ...
   dataBuf, err := make([]arbitrary_struct_type, numRecs)
   ...
   return dataBuf, err
}

func main() {
   ...
   a, err := readDataset(grp1, structA)
   ...
   b, err := readDataset(grp2, structB)
   ...
   c, err := readDataset(grp3, structC)
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to return a slice and not an array.

You can use [`reflect.MakeSlice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#MakeSlice) function to make slice, and to get type of the arbitrary object you can use [`reflect.TypeOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf)  function

I'm doing something similar in https://github.com/strongo/app/blob/master/db/interfaces.go & https://github.com/strongo/app/blob/master/gaedb/database.go which are used in https://github.com/strongo/bots-framework

Comment: Can't I make the signature something like: func readDataset(grp *Group, a type) ([]arbitrary_struct_type, error)?  But, that doesn't solve how I'll pass the return value.

Comment: You return either `interface{}` or `[]interface{}` or if you can you can define some interface and return `[]YourInterface`.

Comment: I've added a link to a code that do similar task of reading entities from DB (specifically Googe AppEngine Datastore)